# F# SignalR Dynamic Class

Tags: f#, signalr

I am working through a tutorial on SignalR using F# and I have run into a problem.  The SignalR IHubConnectionContext has an .All property that is dynamic.  You are supposed to define the method here that the client will wire up to receive notifications from the server.  It works fine in C#.  However, in F#, I am getting:

> The field, constructor or member 'yourMethodHere' is not defined

Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: just an idea: maybe signalr is not compatible with F#, because they are usually testing it on C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used self hosting signalr in F# it works just fine. I also have two different libraries that can bridge this gulf you are having.

**A.**

You can use my apache licensed open source library [FSharp.Interop.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Interop.Dynamic/) (`PCL w/ .net 4.5, WinRT, Silverlight 5.0`) that implements the late binding operator `?` using the `DLR`.

```
open FSharp.Interop.Dynamic
```

...

```
Clients.All?yourMethodHere(some, args)
```

**B.**

If you want a little more typing. I also wrote another apache licensed library [ImpromptuInterface](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ImpromptuInterface) (`.net 4.0 or Silverlight 5.0`) that will generate an Interface to dlr proxy. Such that you can define an interface to talk to dlr objects.

```
type IClientsAll =
    abstract yourMethodHere : string * string -> unit
```

...

```
open ImpromptuInterface
```

...

```
let clientsAll = Clients.All.ActLike<IClientsAll>()
clientsAll.yourMethodHere(some, args)
```

Comment: There is also an option *C.* worth mentioning. If you cast Clients.All to `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.ClientProxy` you can call `clientsAll.Invoke("yourMethodHere", some, args)`, but I'd be hesitant to do that, while the class and method are `public`, the fact that it is named "Proxy" and there there isn't anything all in the project that references that Type or Method, I'd worry about future changes to the library possibly breaking it. The DLR api is the libraries intended use, and methods A. & B. are more ideal, but if someone was in a crunch, as a last resort C. is also possible.